# To run a shell script (with parameters) on Windows command line via putty.exe

Tags: linux, bash, batch-file, putty

I need to execute a batch script which runs the shell script remotely inside the Linux box.

Now, everything is working fine, but the script fails to execute if I try to give a **command line parameter** to the shell script.

Working -> ex

> C:\temp\Testing>putty.exe -pw "blabla" -m "test-script.sh"
>   bob@10.20.110.57

But if I try to give arguments it fails to execute. Example:

**Not Working**

> C:\temp\Testing>putty.exe -pw "blabla" -m "test-script.sh **ok-1**"
>   bob@10.20.110.57

```
 where ok-1 = command line argument for local script test-script.sh
```

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: From [the documentation](http://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/0.62/puttydoc.txt) : "the `-m' option expects to be given a local file name, and it will read a command from that file."

Comment: @dystroy, thanks for the suggestion. What I draw from your response is , your suggesting me to use -m option, . I have used -m option and it wors like a charm but if i want my bash script (which resides locally) to accept command line argument ( ok-1 in this case ) how would i implement that

Comment: @samantha - I don't think you can achieve what you are trying through the `-m` option. `-m` option is to provide a command text file and that command text file is taken as is and executed on target server. `-m` as far as I know, is not designed to consider what follows as a command line syntax. Instead `-m` tells putty to grab the file mentioned after `-m` and execute it remotely. So, when you provide a command line argument, say `ok-1`, putty thinks of `ok-1` as a file.HTH. I can provide an alternate way to do what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @ring bearer, Thanks a lot for detailed explanation. your solution has cleared few of my doubts.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of using `putty.exe`, you can use `pscp` and `plink` (utilities that come with PuTTY) to do this.  Use a command like this:

```
pscp.exe -pw "blabla" test-script.sh bob@10.20.110.57:/some/path/
```

to copy the script to the remote server, and then use a command like this:

```
plink.exe -ssh -pw "blabla" bob@10.20.110.57 /some/path/test-script.sh ok-1
```

to execute it.

Comment: Thanks for solution. Being late in Uk , I will try it tomorrow in office and let you guys know if it works.  Thanks again

Comment: Hi @bta, I tried your command  from cmd.exe on window  but it fails . I got error like "bash: ok-1: command not found"

Comment: @samantha- Whoops, I made a typo on my `plink` command.  There shouldn't be a colon between the server address and the command to run.  See my edited answer for the correct syntax.